# How to set a record on every click in localstorage and get all those list of records?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to get all the lists when I storing the object records in local storage on every button clicks.

I tried like below, but on every click getting the same record which setting in present click, not getting previous clicks set records.

```
$scope.AddToCart = function () {
var items = [];
var listItems = {
                Garment: list.ItemName,
                Quantity: itemQty,
                Price: list.DryClean,
                Service: service,
                Total: totalPrice
            };
items.push(listItems);
localStorage.setItem('listItems', JSON.stringify(items));
var stored = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("listItems"));
console.log(stored);
```

I would like to get like below

On first click : `0: {Garment: "Thobe", Quantity: "1", Price: 5, Service: "", Total: 5}`

On second click :

```
0: {Garment: "Thobe", Quantity: "1", Price: 5, Service: "", Total: 5}
1: {Garment: "Shirt", Quantity: "1", Price: 20, Service: "", Total: 25}
```

on third click :

```
0: {Garment: "Thobe", Quantity: "1", Price: 5, Service: "", Total: 5}
1: {Garment: "Shirt", Quantity: "1", Price: 20, Service: "", Total: 5}
2: {Garment: "Pant", Quantity: "1", Price: 30, Service: "", Total: 55}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `var items = [];` outside to the `$scope.AddToCart` function.

```
var items = [];
$scope.AddToCart = function() {
    var listItems = {
      Garment: list.ItemName,
      Quantity: itemQty,
      Price: list.DryClean,
      Service: service,
      Total: totalPrice
    };
    items.push(listItems);
    localStorage.setItem('listItems', JSON.stringify(items));
    var stored = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("listItems"));
    console.log(stored);
```